Upgrading from Shimano 50/34 to 53/39, on a 10 speed bike...can I use a 11s chainrings?
I actually own a Pinarello FP3 with a 6750 Ultegra groupset: it is a 10 speed, 50x34 groupset. I use it with a 11-32 cassette.
Since I'm doing some races, especially on flat circuits, I'm planning to increase the big ring to a 53, or a 52 at least.
From what I understood from a bit of research, it seems that:

The 6750 only came with the 50x34 rings;
The alternative should be the 6700, which comes with 52x36 and 53x39. The sad thing is that it's out of production from Shimano, and it's also out of stock in every shop I browsed.

I know that the 53x39 rings is present on more recent series, for example the R7000, which is - by the way - classified as 11 speed.
My question is: can I install the R7000 (or another, 11 speed chainrings) even if the rest of the groupset (and the frame itself) is 10 speed?
Thank you all.

Yes you can install the 11sp chainset or buy 110bcd 5-arm chainrings for your existing set.

Note also that the frame itself is not limited to 10-speed. The limiting factors may be that most recent groupsets are for hydraulic disc brakes, and electronic (so you need to make sure that the frame is "Di2 compatible" for Shimano (there's a Di2 12-speed Ultegra for rim brakes for example). But that's not linked to the number of speeds. I don't know if SRAM has a electronic groupset that works with rim brakes, but their groupset are totally wireless, so can work on any frame (you'll need to change the free hub body though).

Are you spinning out on the 50x11?

The difference in pin length between 10 and 11 speed chains is basically the smallest jump of any; it's around 0.2mm and change total, or 0.1mm per side. It typically works without issue to just put 10 speed chains on 11 speed doubles without doing anything extra. If you needed to, you can put 0.1mm microshims under the small ring to dial it further if there's rub.
TA made 52 and 53 5-bolt 110 rings specifically to match the spider contour of FC-6750. The 53 may be hard to find now. You'd pair these with their matching 39x110.
